# Can my older Nvidia video card work with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, gpu-driver

I  have a NVIDIA NV37GL Quadro PCI-E Series rev a2 video card.

I have been trying unsuccessfully to install **Ubuntu 14.04**. So far I either get a black screen or the back splash with no unity. I have tried to purge Nvidia and add the recommended driver (173) using various methods. I have also tried using *nvidia-current*.

I am wondering if anyone has this card and has successfully installed a fully working Ubuntu **14.04** or do I accept I have to install **12.04**?

I'm editing this comment in the hopes of bumping it and looking for newer information. So I have spent hours trying to get this card to work with 14.04 and finally gave up and went back to 12.04 but now I cannot get it to work either.
I will be detailing this in a separate post because it deals with 12.04 but it seems to involve the nvidia module tainting kernel.
Any new input would be great or should I just dump the computer and the old graphics card. It just seemed to almost work so I can't seem to let it go

Answer (score 0):

I think this user had have same problem with you.Maybe you want to look it.
**[Problem video nvidia ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130170/problem-video-nvidia-ubuntu-12-04)**

And maybe you crashed your driver packages. Fix your drivers :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then delete all Nvidia driver with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then install Nvidia newest driver for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And you have to restart your computer. I hope helped you!

Comment: I had done a number of clean installations but I did try this and sadly it still did not work